# How do I set the memory split for 512MB model?

Tags: memory

I have just received the 512MB model. However, there are no options for memory split.

I'm running the latest and greatest `2012-09-18-wheezy-raspbian.img`.

See the video question (30 sec): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PENjgvxZkZo

**How do I set the memory split for the 512MB model?**

Comment: correct for what usage? The memory split for learning shell scripting is going to be very different from that for running a media center.

Comment: In general :) I just wanted to know how to edit. Suggesting creating new tag: 512MB (not enough reputation)

Answer (score 9):

There is an updated firmware package available for the new 512mb Pi's. You can find the link in this [announcement about the new upgraded Pi's](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/2180), which allows you to utilize all of the Pi's memory and control how that memory is split between the GPU/CPU.

You may want to read these posts http://www.raspians.com/updating-the-memory-split-for-the-512-mb-raspberry-pi/ or
http://hubcitylabs.org/unlocking-your-new-raspberry-pis-512mb-of-memory/ which explain how to set the memory split for the new Pi's.

Answer (score 2):

Having analyzed, tried, and experienced three links (credit to @Steve) that are constanly being updated here is the answer that works for me as of momemt of writing:

```
rm -rf /boot/*.elf /boot/*.bin /boot/*.img
apt-get install git
apt-get install ca-certificates
wget http://goo.gl/1BOfJ -O /usr/bin/rpi-update && sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/rpi-update
/usr/bin/rpi-update
```

Do not mistype `0` with `O`, in the snippet above both are capital O for October.

[image: Do not mistype]

To see if the new memory is allocated type `free` in the console to see **free** (available) memory.

Comment: When using these instructions I found that I would get the error `start.elf not found` when running rpi-update. To fix this I ran `cd /boot` and `wget https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/boot/start.elf` and then ran `rpi-update` again.